# Making changes in beforeCommit() in VOImpl in ADF

Tags: oracle-adf

I have a requirement in which i need to correct wrong data before it is completely posted to the DB...

I found that validations can be done in View Object Impl Class. I tried to make changes in the Code with the following code:

```
public void beforeCommit(TransactionEvent e) {

Row row = this.getCurrentRow();

Row[] locationRows = this.getAllRowsInRange();

System.out.println(this.getCurrentRowIndex());

for (int i = 0; i < locationRows.length; i++) {
    System.out.println(locationRows[i].getAttribute("PortSequenceNo"));
    locationRows[i].setAttribute("PortSequenceNo", 100 + i);
    this.validate();
    System.out.println("validated");
    this.postChanges(e);
    System.out.println("Changes posted");

}

validatePSN(locationRows);

super.beforeCommit(e);
}
```

But this code is giving below error :

> javax.faces.el.EvaluationException: oracle.jbo.JboException:
>   JBO-28202: Entities invalidated in beforeCommit(). Need to revalidate
>   and post.     at
>   org.apache.myfaces.trinidadinternal.taglib.util.MethodExpressionMethodBinding.invoke(MethodExpressionMethodBinding.java:58)
>     at
>   org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.component.UIXComponentBase.broadcastToMethodBinding(UIXComponentBase.java:1433)

Please help in as what should i do so that i can make the last minute changes to the actual values posted through the ADF form

Comment: The exception message says that: 
"Fix any business logic that invalidates entity instances in postChanges() such that there are no more invalid entities after all changes are posted during the commit cycle."
(http://docs.oracle.com/cd/A97337_01/ias102_otn/buslog.102/bc4j/jboerrormessages.html#28202)
Can you move the code which modifies the data outside of beforeCommit()? i.e move it to postChanges() and then try?

Answer (score 0):

Use the doDML method of the EntityImpl class.

Javadoc:
[EntityImpl doDML method](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B14099_19/web.1012/b14022/oracle/jbo/server/EntityImpl.html#doDML_int__oracle_jbo_server_TransactionEvent_)

> Override this method to provide custom logic for processing inserts,
>   updates, and deletes.

Answer (score 0):

You should override method `protected void prepareForDML(int operation, TransactionEvent transactionEvent)`.
At this point you can safely modify values of attributes.